# Python gdal projection information

Tags: python, postgresql, leaflet, gdal

I'm using the gdal_polygonize python script to polygonize a raster image and store the polygons in a postgres database. So far everything worked fine.

```
gdal_polygonize.py abia.tif -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='abiaDB' host='127.0.0.1' port='5434' user='postgres' password='****'" mylayer
```

After storing the data in the database I export it from there as a GeoJson file, which I want to display with Leaflat. Therefore Leaflat only works with the projection EPSG:4326. Therefore I used the proj4.js Plugin, which does a conversion from the Gauss-Kruger zone 4 EPSG:31468 projection. So I have to define the original projection manualy in the code like that:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:31468', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs');

L.Proj.geoJson(data, {
  'pointToLayer': function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
  }
 }).addTo(map);
```

Is there a way that I can say the python script that it also should store the projection info in the database. My aim is that the visualization is more automated, so when there is a other image, with a other projection it should get the projection info from the database. Is there a way that I can say the gdal_polygonize function that it should store the information in an extra row or something like that?

Polygonize Java

```
gdal.AllRegister();
ogr.RegisterAll();
args = gdal.GeneralCmdLineProcessor(args);

//Open source file
Dataset hDataset = gdal.Open(args[0], gdalconstConstants.GA_ReadOnly);        
Band rasterBand = hDataset.GetRasterBand(1);
Band maskBand = rasterBand.GetMaskBand();

Driver driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("Memory");
DataSource dataSource =  driver.CreateDataSource("mem");

SpatialReference srs = null;
if(!hDataset.GetProjectionRef().isEmpty())
    srs = new SpatialReference(hDataset.GetProjectionRef());

Layer outputLayer = dataSource.CreateLayer("mylayer", srs);
FieldDefn field_def = new FieldDefn("DN",ogr.OFTInteger);
outputLayer.CreateField(field_def);
gdal.Polygonize(rasterBand, maskBand, outputLayer, 0, new Vector<>(), new TermProgressCallback());   

//Transformation       
DataSource dataDest = driver.CreateDataSource("mem2");
//Create destination projection
SpatialReference dst = new SpatialReference();
dst.ImportFromEPSG(4326);

 CoordinateTransformation ct = CoordinateTransformation.CreateCoordinateTransformation(srs, dst);

//Write data to database
DataSource dataSourceDb = ogr.Open( "PG:dbname='abiaDB' host='127.0.0.1' port='5434' user='postgres' password='****'", 1 );
dataSourceDb.CopyLayer(outputLayer, "mylayer");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is that you could modify [gdal_polygonize.py](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_polygonize.py) to re-project the result. Use a MEM driver to store the interim polygonised result from `dst_layer`, then reproject using the osr module.

Another idea that is much simpler is to make a database VIEW that projects a table's geometry column with SRID=4326 using [postgis](/questions/tagged/postgis), i.e.

```
CREATE VIEW mytable_latlong AS
  SELECT gid, ST_Transform(geom, 4326) AS geom, ...
  FROM mytable
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I did it in Java, added the code above. In this example I write after the polygonize the result to the database. Do you have an example how to do the conversion before writing it to the database?

Comment: Ok, I things with storing to the result to mem and writing it then to the database works. I only have problems doing the transformation.